# Was there any case of Yadav men marrying Kshatriya women?

Tags: mahabharata, marriage, caste-system, yadavas

Was there any case of Yadav men marrying Kshatriya women ? Duryodhan daughter married son of Krishna , but Duryodhan opposed it.

Was there any such instance where Yadav men married Kshatriya women and it was considered as okay by everyone ?

Comment: Yadavas are Kshatriyas themselves. You are confusing Ahir with Kshatriyas. Ahir are the cowherd community classified as Vaishyas/ Shudras variously. Overtime some Yadava kings took on them name Ahir as respect for the linkage of their ancestor Krishna with the Ahirs in his childhood.

Comment: @Adiyarkku Yadavas were not Kshatriyas. Yadu who was progenitor of the race was born from a Kshatriya father (Yayati) and Brahmin mother (Devyani). So, they were Soota. Even Yayati cursed Yadu that his descendants will be PratilomShankars.